# There is no style applied when using Reactstrap with Parcel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap, parceljs

I'm using `parcel` to bundle my code and `reactstrap` to style my `react` app. I have an example:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "reactstrap";

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <header></header>
      <Button color="danger">Danger!</Button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

This supposes to create a nice red button. But when I run the app with `parcel` (in dev mode), it gives me a plain button, however the button is applied a `classname` (`btn btn-danger`) on it. Here is the result:

[image]

What's wrong with `parcel` and `reactstrap`? How can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [`bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) package and then add `bootstrap.min.css` inside your `index.js` file:

#### Install [`bootstrap`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) package:

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

#### Add `bootstrap.min.css` to your `index.js` file:

```jsx
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought `reactstrap` had already included `bootstrap`!